# type a simple "©" in STS on a macbook pro

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, springsource

I have a simple but realy annoying problem:
I just can't manage to type a simple "©" in STS (SpringSource Tool Suite) on my macbook pro.
In any other editor (even plain eclipse) or application I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> as a shortcut, but this does not work in my STS 2.3.3.M2 and was also not working with 2.3.2.
Any idea whats wrong?

thanks 
.domi

Comment: You are referring to ©, not @

Comment: Try the Option key on the other side?

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm talking about '@' - don't know how '@' got replaced with '©' in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a combination of a bug in the groovy plugin and my keyboard layout (de_CH). The bug now is fixed: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-808

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> shortcut is taken. In Preferences select General/Keys from the left-hand tree, and try to find the binding in the list (in the generic Eclipse workbench it is not taken).

A semi-automatic way to find taken solution is to add it to a command, and let the system display conflicts.

Comment: I tried to add a new shortcut with the same keys, but eclipse did not display any conflicts. But if i use 'alt + G' in the groovy editor, it comes up with a choice of six grails editor shortcuts, all starting with 'option + G' ("alt + G"). So it seems that the grails tooling some how intercepts the shortcut...

Comment: Ok, this means, a simple Alt+G does not get detected for these shortcuts. But you can look for the corresponding shortcuts (the names displayed in the choice menu are the same names as in the Command list), and there you can either disable or remap the shortcuts.

Comment: i tried this, but no luck. I created a JIRA for it: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-808